# ASP.Net Core 2.0 mixed authentication of JWT and Windows Authentication doesn't accept credentials

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, authorize-attribute

I've API created in asp.net core 2.0 where I am using mixed mode authentication. For some controllers JWT and for some using windows authentication.

I've no problem with the controllers which authorize with JWT. But for the controllers where I want to use windows authentication I am indefinitely prompted with user name and password dialog of chrome.

Here my sample controller code where I want to use Windows Authentication instead of JWT.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("processUpload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessUploadAsync(UploadFileModel uploadFileModel)
    {

    }
}
```

My configure services code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     })
     .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
     {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,       
            ValidateIssuer = false,  
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("blahblahKey")),
            ValidateLifetime = true, //validate the expiration and not before values in the token
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) //5 minute tolerance for the expiration date
        };
     });

     // let only my api users to be able to call 
     services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
     {
        auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
            .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, "MyApiUser").Build());
     });

     services.AddMvc();
}
```

My configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication(); //needs to be up in the pipeline, before MVC
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Appreciate your suggestions and help on this.

Update: Till now I've been debugging my code on chrome. But when I have used IE 11, the above code is running without any issue.

Can this be CORS issue of chrome where preflight issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to ensure, that you **NOT** setting `Authorization: Bearer <JWT_token>` HTTP header when you trying to use Windows Auth.

Comment: I have tried your code - if I've used the JWT token into controller which is protected via Bearer auth and return 401, I get the pop dialog for putting the credentials - any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Jenan, you are getting windows credentials pop up because you even copied the code of "[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]" which is windows authentication. If you dont need authentication at controller level move it to action level and also to JWT.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to ensure, that you **NOT** setting `Authorization: Bearer <JWT_token>` HTTP header when you trying to use Windows Auth. The key point here is how "Windows Auth" actually works. Let's look how it works with browser for example.

Let's call this "a normal flow":

1. You navigate to `http://example.com/api/resource` in your browser;
2. Your browser send a HTTP GET request to `http://example.com/api/resource` without any **`Authorization`** HTTP Header for now (an anonymous request);
3. Web server (or WebAPI themself) recieve a request, find out, that there is no **`Authorization`** header and respond with `401 Not Authorized` status code with **`WWW-Authenticate: NTLM,Negotiate`** HTTP Header setted up (*"Go away, no anonymous access. Only 'NTLM' or 'Negotiate' guys are welcome!"*);
4. Browser receive a `401` response, find out that request was anonymous, looks to **`WWW-Authenticate`** header and instantly repeat request, now with **`Authorization: NTLM <NTLM_token>`** HTTP Header (*"Ok, take it easy, mr. Web server! Here is my NTLM token."*);
5. Server receive a second request, find NTLM token in **`Authorization`** header, verify it and execute request (*"Ok, you may pass. Here is your resource."*).

Things goes a little different, when you initialy set **`Authorization`** header to some value:

1. Your JS require `http://example.com/api/resource` with JWT authorization;
2. Your browser send a HTTP GET request to `http://example.com/api/resource` with **`Authorization: Bearer <JWT_token>`** HTTP Header now;
3. Web server (or WebAPI themself) recieve a request, find out, that there is **`Authorization`** header with "Bearer" authentication scheme and again respond with `401 Not Authorized` status code with **`WWW-Authenticate: NTLM,Negotiate`** HTTP Header setted up (*"Go away, we don't know who are this 'Bearer' guys, but we don't like them. Only 'NTLM' or 'Negotiate' guys are welcome!"*);
4. Browser receive a `401` response, find out that request **was** authorized and decide that this token is bad. But, as you actually set **`Authorization`** header, this means that you actually **have** some credentials. And so it ask you for this credentials with this dialog.

Comment: Good explanation and thanks for your time. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same need. I'm not yet running things on IIS, only Kestrel, but I managed to adapt Microsoft's [own instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to get per controller/controller method authentication using JWT and Windows auth.

All I did was modify Startup.cs/ConfigureServices from

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // should be set to true in production
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = generateTokenValidationParameters();
});
```

to this

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddNegotiate()
.AddJwtBearer(x => 
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // should be set to true in production
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = generateTokenValidationParameters();
});
```

So, basically, removed the Default Authentication and Challenge scheme, added Negotiate (Windows Auth) and JwtBearer using my pre-existing JWT configuration.

In the controllers, I enabled Windows Authentication by adding this authorization header

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

And similarly, I replaced my existing Authorization headers that previously did JWD (given that it was the default auth/challenge scheme) with this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

My app will be hosted by Kestrel, so IIS won't be an issue, but I'll try that next, anyway.

@edit: I've now mastered IIS Express, too. Enabled Windows Auth through VS's IIS Express settings (Project Properties, Debug tab), then ensure that IIS does not perform automatic authentication for in and out of processing hosting by adding this to Startup.ConfigureServices (right after AddAuthentication).

```
//disable automatic authentication for in-process hosting
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => 
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});

//disable automatic authentication for out-of-process hosting
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => 
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});
```

I then changed my test controller to have a method with the following authorize header

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

And when I access that method with a browser that trusts the URL, I'm being let in and User.Identity is my windows identity.

Now off to see if that also works on an actual IIS.

Comment: Umpf, pulled the trigger too soon. Where I want windows auth only, I get it (both in IIS Express and IIS), where I want no authentication at all, it also works. But where I try to Authorize with scheme Bearer, IIS will respond with a 401 offering Bearer, Negotiate and NTLM instead of just returning bearer. tried setting DefaultAuthenticationScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme, but to no avail. It all works exactly as expected on Kestrel. Even completely discarding anything that has to do with windows auth in Startup.cs doesn't remove the unwanted auth schemes :(