# Architecture for WPF with local AD Windows Auth and Remote 3rd party WebApi?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

Scenario is a desktop WPF app that we desire to have no login (i.e. uses windows auth against on-prem AD).  WebApi that supports app is in the cloud and currently uses Jwt against in-app user DB.

What is the best approach for a hybrid auth where users in the on-prem AD can get automatically authenticated into the app and Authentication/Authorization in the WebApi is also satisfied?

Do I need to sync the AD into the AppDb? (probably frowned upon)
Do I need to deploy the app with a proxy of some sort to Auth the web client?

Basically there will be two separate authorities for User Stores and I'm not sure of the best approach to glue them together if it's possible at all.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146938/how-to-combine-the-windows-authentication-and-jwt-with-net-core-2-1

Comment: I don't think so because WebApi is running on IIS in Azure, so adding WindowsAuthentication there doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I see, I expected your on-premise AD synced with azure AD. Hence the link.

Comment: The WebApi has in-app user DB.  Thanks for the suggestion though!