# How to authenticate windows user in a intranet Nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I developed a web app using React and NodeJS for the company I am working at. I set up authentication using JWT (Using a login HTML form) but now I am required to authenticate users in the web app using the windows credential. I am hosting the React app in IIS on a server inside the company's local network.

What are the options to get this task done? Thanks for your comments.

I have tried Passport-windowsauth.

Comment: You can see different approaches to take Windows authentication credentials (HTTP header) and convert to JWT token, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146938/how-to-combine-the-windows-authentication-and-jwt-with-net-core-2-1

Comment: You can use LDAP for that, and if the credentials are ok, create a JWT.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can I make it to work without need to enter manually the credentials? I am in a point it is working but the web browser gives my a popup  asking for my credentials. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to set this is client browser, add the site to Local Intranet. `Chrome > Settings > Advanced > System > Open Proxy Settings > Security (tab) > Local Intranet > Sites (button) > Advanced.`