# ASP.NET Core JWT/Windows Authentication HTTP 400 Error

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API which currently requires users to enter a username/password to recieve a JWT for authorization. I want to add the option of using Windows Authentication to recieve a JWT as well. Ultimately, I plan to have two authorization controllers, one for username/password, the other for Windows Auth.

To test this, I first enabled Windows Authentication in IIS express, by right clicking on my project and going to Properties.

[image: Hey look, windows auth!]

Then, I made a simple test controller to see if I could authenticate with my Windows Credentials.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
[Route("api/ping")]
public class PingController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Pong" };
    }
}
```

This seemed to work, as when I navigated to this endpoint in my browser, the screen displayed `Pong` as expected.

However, I run into problems when I try and access any of my other controllers that use Bearer Authentication Schemes. The controllers declare their Authentication Scheme like so:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Whenever I make a request to one of these controllers I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.
```

This same request works just fine with Windows Authentication turned off.

How can I enforce Windows Authentication on some controllers and Bearer Authentication on others?

Comment: Hope this question helps you  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053459/asp-net-core-2-0-mixed-authentication-of-jwt-and-windows-authentication-doesnt

Comment: Just split the project into 2 projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I enforce Windows Authentication on some controllers and Bearer Authentication on others?

Firstly, I have to say it is somehow weird when dealing with the mixed schemes of JWT and Windows Authentication. I mean when an user who is not authenticated by `JwtBearer`, tries to access those url resources protected by `JwtBearer` Scheme, will be challenged by Windows authentication.

Secondly, as for your question, we can **configure the `JwtBearer` authentication to use a custom token which is not used as the `HTTP` header (i.e. `Authorization: Bearer xxxx_yyyy_zzz`)** . For example, send the `JWT` token by querystring or a custom header.

#### How to In Details :

Configure the `JwtBearer` authentication to read token from querystring:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options=> {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents() {
                OnMessageReceived = async (context) =>{
                    var bearer=context.HttpContext.Request.Query["bearer"].FirstOrDefault();
                    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bearer)){
                        context.Token = bearer;
                    }
                },
            };
        });
```

For a testing purpose, I add a dummy policy handler for your `MyPolicy`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o => {
    o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",p => {
        p.Requirements.Add(new MyPolicyRequirement());
    });
});
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,MyPolicyRequirementHandler>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Here the `MyPolicyRequirementHandler` is :

```
public class MyPolicyRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyPolicyRequirement>
{

    public MyPolicyRequirementHandler()
    {
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user= context.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And the two controllers protected by the Authentication of `Windows` or `JwtBearer` :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Pong" };
    }
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy ="MyPolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Bar" };
    }
}
```

#### Test Case :

**Test with Windows Authentication**

A Screenshot when accessing the `/api/ping`

[image]

**Test with Jwt Bearer Authentication**

Firstly, generate a `JwtToken` on server side :

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Iml0bWludXMiLCJuYmYiOjE1NDIzNDMxNzMsImV4cCI6MTU0MjQxNTE3MywiaWF0IjoxNTQyMzQzMTczLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM4NSIsImF1ZCI6IndlYmNsaWVudCJ9.iMnq8UBRQforNeRBehrULAScD8D2-ta4nmdQt1rTZ3s
```

And then send a HTTP GET request to the endpoint of `/api/foo` with a querystring of `bearer=xxx_yyy_zzz` :

```
GET https://localhost:44385/api/foo?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Iml0bWludXMiLCJuYmYiOjE1NDIzNDMxNzMsImV4cCI6MTU0MjQxNTE3MywiaWF0IjoxNTQyMzQzMTczLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM4NSIsImF1ZCI6IndlYmNsaWVudCJ9.iMnq8UBRQforNeRBehrULAScD8D2-ta4nmdQt1rTZ3s HTTP/1.1
```

it will return `[foo]` as expected :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcMTZcV2luZG93c0F1dGh0ZW50aWNhdGlvbkFuZEp3dEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uXEFwcFxhcGlcZm9v?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

["Bar"]
```

Comment: //when an user who is not authenticated by JwtBearer, tries to access those url resources protected by JwtBearer Scheme, will be challenged by Windows authentication// - Is it possible to avoid this behaviour while retaining both auth schemes?

Comment: @Jones have you got the answer for this? I'm having the same struggle. Couldn't figure out how to do mixed authentication but JWT endpoint shouldn't challenge by Windows Authentication. I don't want to make a different app to generate token.

Comment: @AngryCoder - Yeap, Windows auth expects token in header `Authorization`. So to work with both, send jwt token in some custom header. I use `JWTToken`.